# I am John Doe <of> CompanyName Corp.?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

Instead of saying

> I am John Doe *from* CompanyName Corp.

is it proper to say

> I am John Doe *of* CompanyName Corp.

?

Comment: Related question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/181943/9161

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are grammatical and correct, I would naturally use the first one in general conversation as a native speaker.